# Use the principle of mathematical induction to prove that $ t_n= \frac{18}{3^n(n-1)!}$ for all $n∈ \mathbb Z^+.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, induction

[Image of question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fQv6.png)

I am really struggling how to prove that t<sub>n</sub> = $\frac{18}{3^n(n-1)!}$ for the sequence where t<sub>1</sub> = 6 and t<sub>n+1</sub> = $\frac{tn}{3n}$

I cannot seem to get past the first step of induction. My method to solve the problem so far includes:

(1) If n = 1,  LHS = 6

RHS = t<sub>1</sub>

=   $\frac{18}{3^1(1-1)!}$

= $\frac{18}{3}$

= 6

LHS = RHS

∴p<sub>1</sub> is true

Assuming  p<sub>k</sub>  is true, n=k

∴ p<sub>k</sub> = $\frac{18}{3^k(k-1)!}$

(2) If p<sub>k+1</sub>  is true, n=k+1

∴ t<sub>k+1</sub>= $\frac{18}{3^k+1(k)!}$

Specifically I am not sure how to show the last line is the case using p<sub>k</sub>

Help would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You assumed that $t_k=\frac{18}{3^k(k-1)!}$ is true for all $k\le n$

It’s left to prove that it is true for $n+1$

We have $t_{n+1}=\frac{t_n}{3n}=\frac{\frac{18}{3^n(n-1)!}}{3n}=\frac{18}{3^{n+1}\times n!}$

Since $n(n-1)!=n!$ and $3\times 3^n=3^{n+1}$

And we are done

Comment: That makes sense. The only thing I do not understand is how n(n−1)!=n! ?

Comment: $n!=n(n-1)(n-2)...(2)(1)$ so $n!=n×((n-1)!)$ since $(n-1)!=(n-1)(n-2)...(2)(1)$